# Megaparsec parse many until given marker with backtracking

Tags: haskell, megaparsec

I'm trying to parse the following input using megaparsec (if this sounds familiar to the advent of code challenge from day 7 2022, it's [because it is](https://adventofcode.com/2022/day/7)):

```
$ cd /
$ ls
dir a
123 foo.txt
dir d
$ cd a
$ ls
dir e
4567 f
78901 h.zip
$ cd e
```

I want to parse it into the following data structure:

```hs
data DirContent = File (Integer, String) | Directory String deriving stock (Show)


data Input
  = Cd DirectoryName
  | CdRoot -- cd /
  | CdPop -- cd ..
  | Ls [DirContent]
  deriving stock (Show)
```

I came up with the following parser:

```hs
import Text.Megaparsec
import Text.Megaparsec.Char

parseFull :: Parsec Void Text [Input]
parseFull = inputParser `sepBy` newline

inputParser :: Parsec Void Text Input
inputParser =
  CdRoot <$ string "$ cd /"
    <|> CdPop <$ string "$ cd .."
    <|> Cd <$> (string "$ cd " *> many alphaNumChar)
    <|> Ls <$> ((string "$ ls" <* newline) *> dirContentParser `sepBy` newline)

dirContentParser :: Parsec Void Text DirContent
dirContentParser =
  Directory <$> (string "dir " *> (pure <$> alphaNumChar))
    <|> curry File <$> decimal <* char ' ' <*> many (alphaNumChar <|> char '.')
```

The idea is that all the lines after a `$ ls` are the results of this command and should be contained in the parsed value. Therefore, the parser has to consume all lines after a `$ ls` until the next line starting with `$` (but without consuming it, because otherwise the following parser will fail).

The parser partly works, but only if there is at most one `ls` command in it and only if it's the last command in the input.
When I run the parser with debug mode, I get the following error:

```
input> IN: "$ cd /<newline>$ ls<newline>dir d<newli <…>
input> MATCH (CERR): "$ cd /<newline>$ ls<newline>dir d<newli <…>
input> ERROR:
input> offset=33:
input> unexpected "$ cd"
input> expecting "dir " or integer
```

as far as I can tell, the `ls` parser doesn't end at the next command. What I would need is a parser that stops when the next `$`  appears, but doesn't consume it and leave it to the next parser. I tried using `try`, but it didn't change anything.
`manyTill_` sounds great, but it consumes the token at the end.

Comment: I'd probably try rolling the newline into the `inputParser`, replacing `dirContentParser \`sepBy\` newline` into `many (dirContentParser <* newline)`. although then you'll need to change every `inputParser` case, aswell as `parseFull`

Comment: maybe `sepEndBy`?

Comment: @Joe I got it to work with your approach. I'd happily accept an answer from you if you want to. If not, I'll post my solution as an answer here

Comment: Feel free to post your solution, glad to hear you got it working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the suggestion in the comments, I came up with the following solution:

```hs
parseFull :: Parsec Void Text [Input]
parseFull = many inputParser

inputParser :: Parsec Void Text Input
inputParser =
  CdRoot <$ string "$ cd /" <* splitter
    <|> CdPop <$ string "$ cd .." <* splitter
    <|> Cd <$> (string "$ cd " *> many alphaNumChar <* splitter)
    <|> Ls <$> (string "$ ls" >> newline *> many (dirContentParser <* splitter))
  where
    splitter = optional newline

dirContentParser :: Parsec Void Text DirContent
dirContentParser =
  Directory <$> (string "dir " *> (pure <$> alphaNumChar))
    <|> curry File <$> decimal <* char ' ' <*> many (alphaNumChar <|> char '.')
```

It doesn't use `sepBy`, but instead parses an optional newline at the end of each line (`newline` optional because otherwise the parser fails if there's no newline at the end of the input)